# What causes Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Signature was not validated successfully?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am using a webservice with a client generated by JAXWS and am now getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Signature was not validated successfully
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:123)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
```

I can't find anything helpful on this problem.  This was working and then stopped working.  What I need to know is what conditions will cause this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the SAML token.  We have multiple servers and we needed to use a different server.